# Баг со скроллом в iOS (iPhone/iPad) -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch;

Tags: javascript, html, css, ios, safari

При таком коде скролл прекрасно и **плавно** скроллит на iPhone , но , время от времени при касаниях и скроллах - скролл перестает работать вообще. Несколько раз потыкав по экрану, возвращается возможность скроллить. Что это может быть и как исправить?

p.s. Если убрать у overlay свойство  **-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;** , ошибка пропадает. Но скролл становится деревянным.

```js
$('button').on('click', function (e){
  $('#overlay').show();
  $('body').addClass('hidden');
});

$('#close').on('click', function (evt) {
  $('#overlay').hide();
  $('body').removeClass('hidden');
});
```

```css
#overlay {
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    z-index: 1000;
 
    /*то самое свойство*/
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
   
}

.hidden {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
}

#popup {
  background: #fff;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#content {
  font-size: 40px;
}

#close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 20px;
  width: 170px;
  height: 50px;
}

body {
  background: url('https://image.freepik.com/free-photo/texture-background_1404-99.jpg') no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 600px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <button>Open popup</button>
  <div id="overlay">
    <div id="popup">
      <div id="content">
        content content content content content content content content content content content content           content content content content content content content content content content content content           content content content content content content content content content content content content           content content content content content content content content content content content content           content content content content content content content content content content content content           content content content content content content content content content content content content           content content content content content content content content content content content content           content content content content content content content content content content content content           content content content content content content content content content content content content           content content content content content content 
      </div>
    </div>
    <button id="close">Close popup</button>
  </div>
<body>
```